# Did the calculator widget break in Lion?

Tags: macos, dashboard-widget, bug

I seem unable to send a "clear" button press from the number pad on my standard apple extended keyboard (aluminum) to the calculator widget in Dashboard on Lion. The regular calculator app works as expected. Strangely, nothing on the internet seems to indicate a known bug.

Comment: I'm able to reproduce the behaviour on my machine. I can't say what's going on with any authority --- that's the first time in a looong time I've broken out the calculator widget --- but I can say it's not just you.

Comment: Probably that Clear key is long gone from any of the keys the QA team tested Lion with. Think of how Lion had been designed with specific new Mac models in mind. Not to excuse the bug, bug just to explain how it could slip through like that.

Comment: Hrm, I wouldn't think the extended aluminum keyboard is going anywhere soon. I am a bit disappointed to see the laptops without a num lock pad, however.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a fix for this bug. Check [my article](http://deepitpro.com/en/articles/Calculator/info/) for details.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! Answers on Ask Different need to be more than just a link. It's okay to include a link, but please summarize or excerpt it in the answer. The idea is to make the answer stand alone. Please take a look at the [FAQs](http://apple.stackexchange.com/faq) for more info. Thanks.

Comment: Very slick! Did you submit this in a bug report? I do also agree with Nathan; if you make this answer a little more verbose, I'll mark it as accepted.